# R HighCharter - customize tool tip captions

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am wanting to customize the popup boxes (I believe called tooltips) on a highcharter chart made in R.

```
# Packages
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

# Here is the data
fake_dat <- tribble(
  ~Project_Name, ~Portfolio, ~Lender, ~Loan_Balance, ~Maturity_Year,
  "Building_1",'Office','Chase',100000,2021,
  "Hotel_1","Hospitality",'Chase',50000,2022,
  "Condo_1","Development","Happy Bank",175000,2023,
  "Building_2","Office","Bank of America",125000,2024)

# Base chart
fake_dat %>%
  hchart("bar", 
     hcaes(x = Project_Name, y = Loan_Balance),
     name = "Loan Balance")
```

When I drag the mouse over the chart bars, it provides a popup box that includes information for Project Name and Loan Balance fields I specificied.

[image]

Is it possible to add additional text for the other fields - Portfolio, Lender, Maturity Year - to display when hovering the mouse over the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `hc_tooltip` and create a custom `JS` formatter.
Graph data is accessible through the `this.point.` property.

```
fake_dat %>%
  hchart("bar", 
         hcaes(x = Project_Name, y = Loan_Balance),
         name = "Loan Balance") %>%
           hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
                            return ('Lender: ' + this.point.Lender + ' <br> Loan balance: ' + this.point.Loan_Balance)
                            }"))
```

[image]