# In Highchart in R, how to edit labels that appears when we hover over points in a scatterplot

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

This is my data frame and my highchart plot:

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), col2 = c(3.54172960518873, 
4.51316494632718, 8.83778709982866, 8.9301479840624, 12.5459778934778, 
12.7053222878864)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df1 %>% 
    hchart(
        "scatter",
        hcaes(x = col1, y = round(col2,2)),
        showInLegend = TRUE,
        color = "#63696b",
        name = "Title 1"
    ) %>%
    hc_title(text ="RMSE",
             align = "center",
             style = list(fontSize = "18px",
                          fontFamily = "Roboto Condensed", 
                          fontWeight = "bold")) %>%
    
     
    hc_yAxis(
        title = list(text = glue::glue("Title 2"),
                     name = "RMSE",
                     style = list(fontSize = "12px",
                                  color =  "black",
                                  fontWeight = "900",
                                  fontFamily = "Roboto Condensed"),
                     labels = list(enabled = TRUE)
                     
        ))
```

When I hover over the point A I have this information bellow:

[image]

I would like to edit it. For example, how do I change the `y` to `A` and remove the `x`?

Any help?

Comment: You can try using `hc_tooltip` with custom javascript formatter as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67610063/3460670)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tooltip.formatter` (or `tooltip.pointFormatter` as well), where you can pass custom JS code to format the tooltip.

**Example:**

```
hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
  return this.key +': <b>' + this.y + '</b>'                          
"))
```

**JS Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fp85rgte/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter